# Facebook Javascript SDK - acces user information

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, sdk

I am suing javascript sdk for my fb application.

The problem I am facing is that I can't save the user information in a variable and than use it in my application where I need it.

This is my code:

```
<script>
var userfb;
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
        FB.api('/me', function(response) {
            userfb = response;
            console.log (userfb);
        });
    }
});
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.firstname input').val(userfb.first_name);
});
</script>
```

This will return userfb.first_name as undefined because FB.api didn't finish yet, but if I write the last line like this, everything works fine.

```
setTimeout(function(){$('.firstname input').val(userfb.first_name);}, 3000);
```

Anyone knows how can I access userfb from anywhere in my application without putting setTimout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to think asynchronous:

```
<script>
var userfb;
$(document).ready(function() {
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        if (response.status === 'connected') {
            FB.api('/me', function(response) {
                userfb = response;
                $('.firstname input').val(userfb.first_name);
            });
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Another solution with a function:

```
<script>
var userfb;

function onConnected() {
    $('.firstname input').val(userfb.first_name);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        if (response.status === 'connected') {
            FB.api('/me', function(response) {
                userfb = response;
                onConnected();
            });
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Of course you can also just get rid of the global variable and use function parameters.